# Buffer-local tangle in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When using Org-mode 8.2.10, setting the `header-args` property does not seem to work as expected with  Common Lisp code blocks. The following does not tangle the code blocks in the file:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle yes
```

Specifying the language explicitly, however, does work:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:lisp :tangle yes
```

According to the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties.html#Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties), `header-args` without a language specifier should work for all code blocks, not just those for Emacs Lisp (which is presumably the default, and what I have working in my init file).

Is this expected behavior, or a subtle bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refresh/activate the `#+PROPERTY:` line by invoking `C-c C-c` with point somehwhere in the line `#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle yes`. After that, you should be able to call `org-babel-tangle` and have it work as expected!

This is not necessary if you use a property drawer, but is for the `#+PROPERTY:` line.

Keep in mind that this applies if you decide to change the `#+PROPERTY:` line too. If you change the line to `#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle no`, those changes will not be registered even if you save the buffer. You will need to call `C-c C-c` again with point on the line for the setup to be refreshed.

I am not sure why `#+PROPERTY: header-args:lisp :tangle yes` worked for you when the other didn't, but I assume that things somehow got refreshed in the meantime, making it seem like one worked and one didn't.

Comment: Interesting. This would imply that the buffer properties are cached in some  way; I'm not sure what the purpose of that would be.

Comment: If you are inclined to dive deeper into how this is implemented, you can start with the documentation and source code for `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` (which you are calling with`C-c C-c` in the `#+PROPERTY` line), and follow the rabbit hole wherever it leads.