# setting an org mode property header doesn't work for the first one

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, r

I cannot seem to set `#+PROPERTY: header-args:R` as the first value and have it work the way I expect it to. This is used as an example for org-mode [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties.html).

Setting a language specific property for `:exports` works. (I've put in some `emacs-lisp` source blocks, and those results do not get shown.

Providing a name for the session does not change the output (i.e. `:session *R*`)

Changing the order just makes the first one not work.

(As an aside, how can I check what a `#+PROPERTY` is set to?)

org-mode 8.3.3 from elpa package. emacs-version 24.5.1 on OSX.

Some minimally working examples follow.

---

### This works:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :session
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :exports both

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x = 3
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x
#+END_SRC
```

resulting in:

```
x = 3
3
x
3
```

### Also this works

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports both
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :session

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x = 3
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x
#+END_SRC
```

and results in the same results as above.

---

### This does not work:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :session
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :exports both

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x = 3
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x
#+END_SRC
```

resulting in:

```
x = 3
3
x
```

### Also does not work

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :exports both
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :session

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x = 3
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
x
#+END_SRC
```

resulting in:

```
x = 3
x
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing `C-c C-c` with point at the `#+PROPERTY` line? Sometimes if you are experiencing unexpected behaviour with properties, they simply haven't been refreshed and are not taking effect. See this answer: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19363/8430

Comment: I have four different files that I've loaded and unloaded multiple times just to make sure the `#+PROPERTY`'s have been in effect. @Tobias has the right answer for me below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `+` to the key to append values to a property.

For an instance, in your last example you should write:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R :exports both
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R+ :session
```

Note the `+` behind the key `header-args:R` in the second line.

See the example

```
 #+PROPERTY: var  foo=1
 #+PROPERTY: var+ bar=2
```

in the orgmode online help http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html.

Note, I wonder myself how the `header-args:c++` property can be set without appending;-).

Comment: I should probably be setting them all at once, all on one line then.

Comment: did this change recently? I still see this in the org-manual, but it does not work for me.

Comment: @wdkrnls Did you activate the file-wide properties by `C-c C-c`?

Comment: @Tobias: No I didn't. Now it works :).